# When does a local String Scanner get garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java.util.scanner

Let's suppose I have a `String s` and I want to iterate through it using a Scanner through this method inside a Builder:

```
private void scan(String s){    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        //do something
    }
}
```

And let's suppose `s` is a variable, part of another `Object`.

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    //rest of code
}
```

Now let's suppose this Object is stored inside a Singleton that stores data to be readily available through the program's lifetime

```
public class Singleton{
    private List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //rest of code
}
```

My question is: what happens to `scanner` once `scan(String s)` has finished running? Would it stay alive or would it, having reached its scope, get collected, thus freeing resources? If it doesn't get collected, what happens if I change `scan(String s)` to:

```
private void scan(String s){    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        //do something
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Or should this latter form be preferred anyway?

Comment: I would always call scanner.close() :P

Comment: The Scanner will persist until some time after the last reference to it is gone.

Comment: (A String Scanner has no resource to close.)

Comment: @HotLicks I meant freeing memory.

Comment: Memory is freed some time after there are no references to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a `Scanner` on a `String`, the Scanner would have a `StringReader` as its source, which would have a reference to the String, but not to the Scanner itself. Since a StringReader is purely in-memory, it doesn't require closing or clean up. There is no harm in closing it, though, but if you do choose to close it, you should put the call to close in a `finally` block, or make it implicit by using try-with-resources:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
try {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        // do something
    }
} finally {
    scanner.close();
}
```

Or:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s)) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        // do something
    }
} // close will be implicitly called
```

The rule is, you should always close *anything you open* to ensure that resources are cleaned up.

In the case of a Scanner on a file, it is important to close it.

In the case of a Scanner on `System.in`, you didn't *open* System.in, so it isn't your responsibility to *close* it.

In the case of a Scanner on a String, or when reading from, say, a `ByteArrayInputStream` or a `StringReader`, there aren't any meaningful resources to be closed, but it might be best to write things in a way where close will be called just in case you switch it later to read from a file (or just to establish the habit).

For your question about garbage collection, you can never actually say when anything will be garbage collected. If your program never runs low on memory, the garbage collector might not even run. But since neither the String nor the StringReader is maintaining a reference to the Scanner, it is *eligible* for garbage collection as soon as the reference to it in your local variable goes away, when method `scan(String)` returns.

Comment: is:

try (Scanner scan = ...) {
    //blabla
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    //blabla
}

a viable choice for files?

Comment: @Angelo Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Closing a Scanner on a file is always preferred so the file resource can be cleaned up deterministically.

The String can be cleaned up after the Scanner is discarded, assuming it is not referenced anywhere else.

For the Scanner I suggest using the try-with-resource

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename)) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the question is about a Scanner on a string, not a file, and when the Scanner can be cleaned up, not the string.

Comment: Indeed. Having the String cleaned up would mean preventing me from calling it again, which would defeat its purpose.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi - What do you mean by "Having the String cleaned up would mean preventing me from calling it again".  What sort of "clean up" do you think might occur on a String?

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi I suggest you keep the String as long as you need it.  It won't be cleaned up while you hold a reference to it, anywhere in your program.

Comment: @HotLicks From my understanding a String either exists or doesn't. So if it stops being accessible it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi ... and stops being accessible when you don't need it any more so it doesn't make sense to worry about need it after it has been cleaned up.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi - If you have a reference to the String then it exists.  If you don't have a reference to it then you don't care whether it exists or not.

Comment: I know, I'm not worried about strings lifetime I'm worried about scanners

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi the scanner's resources will be cleaned up whether you close it or not once it is out of scope. However, it is best practice to clean it up deterministically once you know you are done rather than wait for the GC to do it at some unknown point.